# CodeIgniter 3 - Change select values depending on the other select

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I have a `carro` table that has a relationship with `marca` and `modelo`, and these two also have a relationship. I first add a *marca*, then when adding a new *modelo*, I must select a *marca* before.

Now, to add a new *carro*, I must select one *marca* and *modelo*. Currently all the registered *modelo* are being listed, but I need to list those related to the selected *marca*. Below is the `select` HTML for the fields.

```
<div class="row">
    <input id="hdn_id_marca" type="hidden" name="hdn_id_marca" value="0"/>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="id_marca">Marca do Carro</label>
        <select id="id_marca" name="id_marca" class="form-control" required>
            <option value="" selected disabled>Selecione</option>
            <?php foreach ($marcas as $m) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $m['id']; ?>">
                    <?php echo $m['nome_marca']; ?>
                </option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="id_modelo">Modelo do Carro</label>
        <select id="id_modelo" name="id_modelo" class="form-control" required>
            <option value="" selected disabled>Selecione</option>
            <?php foreach ($modelos as $m) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $m['id']; ?>">
                    <?php echo $m['nome_modelo']; ?>
                </option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

These values are retrieved from the database, it is not any static value. I have tried to create an Ajax:

```
$('#id_marca').change(function() {
    var selectedId = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    $('#hdn_id_marca').attr('value', selectedId);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/admin/modelos/select_by_id_marca',
        data: {'hdn_id_marca': selectedId},
        type: 'POST',
        success: function() {
            alert(data)
        }
    });
});
```

But I then I get

> POST XHR http://localhost:8000/admin/modelos/select_by_id_marca [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 53ms]

**Edit 2**

Below is my `select_by_id_marca()` method. I have also updated the previous code by adding the `hidden` field this method is suppose to have access to. After some changes, I fixed the reason for the 500 error to be happening, but now, the field is not populated only with the *modelo* according to the selected *marca*.

```
public function select_by_id_marca()
{
    $data = array();

    $this->db->order_by($this->primary_key, 'DESC');
    $this->db->get_where('marca', array('id' => $this->input->post('hdn_id_marca')));
    $query = $this->db->get('marca');

    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    $query->free_result();

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: add your `select_by_id_marca` function.

Comment: Just as a sidenote, for those who are wondering: *carro* = *car*, *marca* = *make*, *modelo* = *model*.

Comment: @Hexaholic you mean that he tries to rich model method? :).. mfgabriel92 can you display your controller action code which you try to rich..

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju Svetlio I have added the method, please look the updated question! Hexaholic marca = brand. :)

Comment: Guys, I have fixed something, now there is no error anymore, but the fields are not selected according to the selected _marca_.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong

```
$this->db->order_by($this->primary_key, 'DESC');
$this->db->get_where('marca', array('id' => $this->input->post('hdn_id_marca')));
$query = $this->db->get('marca');
```

You are using both `get_where()` and `get()`. It should be

```
$this->db->order_by($this->primary_key, 'DESC');
$query = $this->db->get_where('marca', array('id' => $this->input->post('hdn_id_marca')));
```

Next,

change

```
return $data;
```

to

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

In ajax success,

```
success: function(data) {
    var a = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(a.id);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way I can  debug it? It did not make any difference, still every value is shown. Maybe I forgot something else?

Comment: did u remove `get` or `get_where`??

Comment: I did exactly as you told so.

Comment: Well, I have tested it by changing the `select`, and the `hidden` field has its `value` changed according to the selected _marca_ id, so I guess it is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98258/discussion-between-mfgabriel92-and-niranjan-n-raju).